# javascript obj vs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui, object

i've got some problem with JS code. When i make array with object my code work well, but whe i'm doing it in **for()** it's doesnt work. This code work good

```
    $(window).load(function () {

    var map = new YMaps.Map(document.getElementById("YMapsID"));
    map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(37.64, 55.76), 10);
    map.addControl(new locationSearchBox()); 

    projects = [{Lat: "lat", Lng: "lng", Address: "address", label: "фывафыва"},
                {Lat: "lat", Lng: "lng", Address: "address", label: "авыва"},
                {Lat: "lat", Lng: "lng", Address: "address", label: "аваы"},
                {Lat: "lat", Lng: "lng", Address: "address", label: "фываl"}];


    console.log(projects);


    $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );   

                map.removeAllOverlays();
                var point = new YMaps.GeoPoint(ui.item.Lng, ui.item.Lat);
                var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(point);
                placemark.name = ui.item.label;
                placemark.description = ui.item.Address;
                map.addOverlay(placemark);
                map.panTo(point, {flying: 1});

            return false;
        }
    })

    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

this one isn't work =(

```
    $(window).load(function () {

    var map = new YMaps.Map(document.getElementById("YMapsID"));
    map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(37.64, 55.76), 10);
    map.addControl(new locationSearchBox()); 

    $.get("data.php",
        function(data){     
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                projects.push({Lat: data[i][0], label: data[i][1], Lng: data[i][3], Address: data[i][2]});
            }           
        }, "json");


    console.log(projects);


    $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );   

                map.removeAllOverlays();
                var point = new YMaps.GeoPoint(ui.item.Lng, ui.item.Lat);
                var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(point);
                placemark.name = ui.item.label;
                placemark.description = ui.item.Address;
                map.addOverlay(placemark);
                map.panTo(point, {flying: 1});

            return false;
        }
    })

    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you, Dima.

Comment: What does 'data' contain when you debug in the second sample? is it populated or is the problem before you get to your for loop? - EDIT: also, I think you should declare your projects variable as projects = []; in the second example just to be sure that JS knows it's an array and will work happily with the .push you're using, I'm not 100% sure it needs that but it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: error messages? You need to tell us what the data object looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous; that's why you need to pass a separate function to `$.get` and you can't just do `var data = $.get(...)`.

The response data will be available a while later because it has to be fetched over the network. In the meantime the rest of your code will execute, which is too early because that code relies on the response.

You will need to move all code that relies on the response data in that function passed to `$.get` (the callback).

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable `projects` as an array in your code before using `.push`.
Use :

```
  projects = [];
```

then use

```
  projects.push({yourObject});
```